# Orders with paypal not listing on user dashboard

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, orders

I have a magento website and I have a problem.

In the user dashboard the orders via Paypal are not listing, it just show a message:"you don't have any order yet", but the orders via cc or other one works perfectly.

I've been exploring sales.xml but I haven't been able to find what can be the cause or how to fix it.

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Are you still interested? I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure that out. The problem is not with Paypal but with the order status "Pending Payment". 
In the file ../Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml find the block that describes the Pending Payment order status and add this line:

```
<visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
```

If you are not sure where to put it just look the rest of the order statuses and see that all of them have the visible_on_front attribute set to 1.
Your code block should look like this:

```
<pending_payment translate="label">
     <label>Pending Payment</label>
     <statuses>
           <pending_payment default="1"/>
     </statuses>
     <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
</pending_payment>
```

Comment: If you would like, accept my answer because it is a correct one. This way people can find the answer.